# Isekai manga about a man who was abandoned by group due to having worthless skills

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I've read the manga before but I can't remember the title and I'm having trouble finding it again. It was about this man who was summoned to another world with a group of other people he doesn't know. They were chosen to save the other world.  Everyone who was summoned gets a skill. One person calls the main character (MC) an old man as he's older than the others. The MC gets a skill that's considered worthless. (I can't remember what the skill is) Anyway the group are sent off into the forest. Everyone decides to abandoned the MC because they believe he'll hold them up. One girl, who was nice to him, doesn't want to do that because it wouldn't be fair to him but the others threaten her if she doesn't do as she's told. The man wakes up and discovers everyone's gone and they didn't leave him with anything, so he has to survive on his own.

If anyone knows what manga I'm talking about please tell me what the title is.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Do you recall if his skills are truly useless, or if they're actually overpowered and just seem useless at first glance?

Comment: @qazmlpok - Of course his skill is insanely OP. That's how these stories work

Comment: I Was Kicked Out Of The Hero’S Party Because I Wasn’T A True Companion So I Decided To Have A Slow Life At The Frontier / The Labyrinth Raids of the Ultimate Tank: The Tank Possessing a Rare 9,999 Endurance Skill was Expelled from the Hero Party / Garbage Brave / Loner Life in Another World

Answer (score 3):

This is *[Yurufuwa Nouka no Moji Bake Skill: Isekai de Katarogu Tsuuhan Yattemasu](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/yurufuwa-nouka-no-moji-bake-skill-isekai-de-katarogu-tsuuhan-yattemasu)*.

> Tatsuya, a **29-year-old** bachelor, gets accidentally summoned to another world and obtains "**Agricultural Skills**." In order to survive, he starts a vegetable garden in a secluded forest. He thought that his life in another world would be extremely difficult, but the ingredients in this other world were delicious and the crops he grew on his own were also very delicious! Furthermore, he's also very happy with the dishes he made with Japanese seasonings!

Slightly-older man gets summoned alongside high school students; they get great skills, he gets farming skills.

They call him an old man:

[image: Ossan]

And ditch him in the forest - with one of the girls that was summoned reluctant to do so, but coerced into it:

[image: Coercion]

They leave him with very little - not quite nothing, but they do take everything the king had given them. He still has some basic survival gear, as he was hiking when he was summoned.